# How can I add many sections of dynamic content in express-handlebars?

Tags: node.js, express, view, express-handlebars

I want to use templates in express-handlebars, i've got a file named "layout.hbs" in a folder called "layouts" inside my views folder for express, i've specified in express view engine config that i want to use handlebars as view engine and i want to use a layout:

```js
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "resources/views"));
app.engine(".hbs", exphbs({
  defaultLayout : "template",
  layoutsDir : path.join(app.get("views"), "layouts"),
  partialsDir : path.join(app.get("views"), "partials"),
  extname : ".hbs",
  helpers : require("./helpers/handlebars/handlebars")
}));
app.set("view engine", ".hbs");
```

It works fine, i can use the layout in my handlebars files, for now i know that i can use the `{{{ body }}}` syntax to put the variable HTML content on the template, so, in my layout.hbs file i have this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/css/style.min.css">
    <title>Welcome!!</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{{ body }}}
</body>
</html>
```

And in my main.hbs file i have this:

```html
<h1>Hello from main!!!</h1>
```

So the final result is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/css/style.min.css">
    <title>Welcome!!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello from main!!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And that's fine, it puts the dynamic content oh the `{{{ body }}}` tag, but now i need to add more sections of dynamic content to my template like styles and scripts that are different for every page, for example, in my main.hbs i want to add this style:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/css/main.min.css">
```

But in contact.hbs i want to add:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/css/contact.min.css">
```

I don't want to add both tags in the layout 'cause when i load the main page i will be loading the contact styles that i don't need and it will make more slower the load of the page.

In Laravel Blade i can do something like:

**Layout.blade.php**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/css/style.min.css">

    @yield('css', "") 

    <title>Welcome!!</title>

</head>
<body>
    @yield('main', "") 
</body>
</html>
```

**main.blade.php**

```
@section('css')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("css/main.min.css") }}">
@endsection

@section('main')
    <h1>Hello from main!!!</h1>
@endsection
```

And it works, how can i do the same in express-handlebars?

Comment: Have you tried adding the link to css files into main.hbs and contact.hbs repectively with a head tag in them?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work, it puts the `<link>` tag inside the body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://wolfgang-ziegler.com/blog/a-scripts-section-for-your-handlebars-layout-template).

Basically, we have to add this helper function to your helpers of express-handlebars:

```js
section: (name, options) => { 
        if (!this._sections) this._sections = {};
         this._sections[name] = options.fn(this); 
         return null;
}
```

And then in your layouts file you can do something like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/css/style.min.css">

    {{{_sections.css}}}

    <title>Welcome!!</title>

</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}

    {{{_sections.scripts}}}
</body>
</html>
```

And in your files you can do this:

```
<h1>Hello from main!!!</h1>


{{#section 'css'}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/css/main.min.css">
{{/section}}

{{#section 'scripts'}}
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/js/main.min.js"></script>
{{/section}}
```

And it will results in:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/css/style.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/css/main.min.css">

    <title>Welcome!!</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello from main!!!</h1>

    <script src="http://localhost:3000/js/main.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

If you want something more similar to Laravel with the default text feature you can add this helper:

```
yield: (name, default_value) => {

    if(typeof default_value == "object") default_value = "";
    return this._sections[name] || default_value;

}
```

And use in your layout:

```
{{{ yield "section_index" "default value" }}}
```